# Jquery Fade in and Slide Down Title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the h1 element of my webpage to slide down from the top and fade in at the same time. Ive tried using animation and it hasnt worked. The effect I am going for is similar to the effect on this apple page. "Thin. Light. Epic." Notice the effect http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/
Right now, it fades in as I would like it, but it does not slide down from the top at all.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function doBoth() {
   "use strict";
   $('h1').hide().slideDown(1000).fadeIn(1000);

   $('a').hide().slideDown(1000).fadeIn(2500);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Photography 101</h1>
        <a href = "#">Enter</a>

      </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 440px;
  text-align:center;

}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 66px;  
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: oblique;
  text-align:center;


}

.jumbotron a {
    top:10px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #000000;

}
```

Comment: Use **[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)** and the way you are using the `document.ready` is not `valid`.. The function has to be either `anonymous` or `named`. You cannot just define function right away there like `function doBoth()`, it can just be like `$(document).ready(function(){....});`

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution. Set `queue:false` to run animation simultaneously

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   "use strict";    
   $("h1").hide().slideDown({duration:2000, queue:false});
    $("h1").hide().fadeIn({duration:2000, queue:false});
    $("a").hide().slideDown({ queue: false, duration: 2000 });
    $("a").hide().fadeIn({duration:2000, queue:false});
 });
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nrc4f3mr/)

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed to do both at the same time but if I did I'd add a class that handled an opacity transition.

## CSS

```
.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron a{
    opacity:0;
    display:none;
    transition:1s opacity ease;
}

.jumbotron h1.visible, .jumbotron a.visible{
    opacity:1;
    transition:1s opacity ease;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('h1, a').addClass('visible').slideDown(1000);
 });
```